# Supports Different language

Tags: android

I have textView and ListView. i made a list of supporting langugage  in listview

when i click any language Textview text needs to change

Code

```
   String lang[] = new String[]{"English","French"};
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lang);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textbox);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        TextView tv = (TextView)v;
        String selected_lang = tv.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(this, selected_lang, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Note:
  Need to Translate From one language to another language without make strings.xml and GoogleApi

Anybody Know How the Google Translate one language into other language ?

Comment: do u want to translate the  text language to french when clicked on french of listview ???

Comment: when i click french need to change the textview and also in listview

Comment: ya that is OK... but what that text view contains earlier and what u need it to change to???

Comment: now its contains Hi,Hello i need to change that Hi,Hello into french language and listview text too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create near your directory values new directory values-fr with file strings.xml and content like

```
<resources>
    <string name="some_string_vith_localization">French translation</string>
</resources>
```

and in your code

```
String lang[] = new String[]{"en","fr"};
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list_id);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lang);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textbox);

    }
            @Override
            protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
                TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_to_change);
                String selected_lang = tv.getText().toString();

                Locale locale2 = new Locale(selected_lang);
                Locale.setDefault(locale2);
                Configuration config2 = new Configuration();
                config2.locale = locale2;
                getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config2,
                        getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                tv.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.some_string_vith_localization));

            }
```

Comment: when i click french in that list box i got an exception 09-07 11:45:44.285: E/AndroidRuntime(712): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f040003

Comment: You shuld have string with id some_string_vith_localization in your string.xml in values folder and in strings.xml in your values-fr foleder.
You can read about this at [tutorial](http://dharmendra4android.blogspot.in/2012/04/some-users-expect-to-use-application-in.html)
And be sure that you have TextView on your activity with id R.id.text_view_to_change and your list view have id R.id.my_list_id.

Comment: on what line do you have this exception?

Comment: i have solved this exception but i dont want to use String.xml and googleAPI
is there is any other way to translater without using these both?

Comment: yes, you can write translation support by you own, but dont see why you dont want to use String.xml  for static strings and googleAPI for dynamic strings

Comment: i am doing some projects in that i don't want to use API`s so that only i need to know any other way to achieve that .. can u give me some link to achieve translation by own

Answer (score 1):

Here is one complete example for [Multiple Language Support in Android](http://dharmendra4android.blogspot.in/2012/04/some-users-expect-to-use-application-in.html#!/2012/04/some-users-expect-to-use-application-in.html) as like you needed.

---

Now,

For that few things are required to understand,

`res/values` folder you can create as many folder and keep the respective language string values in `Strings.xml` file under the folder.

now when the user select any language of it's choice then change the `configuration`

I also suggest that you should also go through once this topic : [Localization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)

Comment: thanks that worked.. In my app i am getting data from webservices in this case how can i change language

Comment: If you are getting dynamic data then you will have to use translate API and AFAIK its not free, and for that also you will have to call and get response according your target language and show it..the better way would be if you can get translated data directly from your web service only...means if you can translate them at server side...
Else the simple answer is translate it using any translater api.

Comment: thanks i have problem in your example.. when i click select language button nothing happens

Comment: Have you created values folder accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

ok... try using the android-translate-api-1.1.jar

link:http://code.google.com/p/android-translate-api/

```
Locale curLocale = this.getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
I18nTranslator i18nTranslator = new I18nTranslator(curLocale .getLanguage());

String text = i18nTranslator.translateString("YOUR-TEXT-HERE");
```