# Display different languages in set in TextView.

Tags: android, utf-8, textview

I have some string in different languages like this :

```
    String aa = " أهلاً و سهلاً"; // arbic
    String arr = "आपका स्वागत है";// hindi
    String str1 = "Tübingen systemportefølje";
    Strings tr2 = "Das ist nicht Englisch"; 
    String str3 = "這是不是英語"; // chinese
```

i want to set these string in text view .i try in this way :

```
try {
            final String s = new String(arr.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
            abc.setText(Html.fromHtml(s));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and also try by adding font respective languages and set view . i only want to set this languages in textview. please give me a hint.

Comment: To achieve localization put different file string.xml in values-lang_code

Comment: check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312010/supports-different-language)

Comment: @TGMCians there is not any other way instead of localization. ?

Comment: The line `final String s = new String(arr.getBytes(), "UTF-8");` is completely useless.

Comment: @BibiTahira Got any Solution for this? i have same problem.

Comment: @YogGuru yes I set font for all languages see this question i did same for all languages http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492398/urdu-font-in-textview

Comment: @BibiTahira Yes, i see above link but my need is the Language is not fix it may be any (Dynamic), may is comes hindi or urdu or any other, You have any hint or solution for this problem?

Comment: @i did for hindi urdu arabic , Japanes , i used some trick add support for all languages by using fonts .