# Urdu font in textview

Tags: android, textview, android-fonts

[image]

i have set urdu in **textview** and apply urdu **typeface** but is only showing word by word like `ب ہ ن`

here is code :

```
Typeface tf1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "Urdu.ttf");
            TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textView.setTypeface(tf1);
            textView.setText("یہ انگریزی نہیں");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Asaalam-o-alakum
bibi Tahira
You can downlaod [urdu Font](http://www.quran.or.kr/urdu/font/font_unicode2.htm) from this link,i have tested it.

Thanks

Comment: @furqi its still same , im testing at 2.2 and 2.3.1 also , its showing good at 4.0 .

Comment: @BibiTahira: try to use different font file bez maybe current font file is corrupted

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK ok me trying with different.

Comment: @BibiTahira see this is working
http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=32fe25e

Typeface tf1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "asunaskh.ttf");
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setTypeface(tf1);
        textView.setText("ی    ہ انگریزی نہیں");

Comment: @furqi i update question added image this is after your given file its not showing full word .

Comment: @BibiTahira : working fine on my end i tried [this](http://www.urdulife.com/font/) urdu font

Comment: I think old sdk version doest not support it so use api 16 or 17

Comment: @prosper which sdk level r u using m wokring on api17 it also working fine for me,but she is working on 2.2

Comment: @BibiTahira : im using Android2.3

Comment: @furqi yeah working fine on 17 and 15 , but not on 8 . anyway thank you furqi for your input .

Answer (score 2):

For Regional languages you need to read them as UTF-8 and then set the font.

I have followed the below steps and working fine.

1. Copy the sample URDU text in ms-word. Check the font of it.
2. Copy the font in assets.
3. While setting the textview text read it as UTF-8
4. Apply the font from Assets.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/burnstown_dam.otf");
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CustomFontText);
    tv.setTypeface(tf);


Typeface tf1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/Jameel Noori Nastaleeq       Urdu.ttf"");
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.CustomFontText);
    textView.setTypeface(tf1);
    textView.setText("یہ انگریزی نہیں");
```

Comment: i am getting data from database and need to display that data in  urdu in textview may i need to put that in urdu in SQlite ? and also how can i show in urdu font in textview android please help me

Comment: above code is for getting font from asset folder you have to check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306702/reading-data-from-sqlite-database-in-android-application

Comment: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Comment: but may i need to insert data in sqlite db in urdu ? or it will automatically convert my text in urdu

Comment: sorry i did not try this, but i think so it is possible in db. see my blog http://usmansaleem.blogspot.com/ i had complete this assignment using java frame.